# AngularJS : Error while using $resource - $save and $query

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an angular service which makes a call to Play server and fetches the JSON object. Below is my code snippets.

**service.js**

```
angular.module('testApp.services',[]).factory('testService',function($resource){

var service = {
    getData : getData
};
function getData(){
    return $resource('http://localhost:9000/testRead',{}, {
            save: {
                    method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                        'Auth-Token': 'B1016693LCAP8154'
                }
            }
    });
}; 
return service;
});
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('testApp.controllers',['testApp.services']).controller('TestController',function($scope, testService){

    testService.getData().save().$promise.then(function(data){
         $scope.output = angular.fromJson(JSON.stringify(data));
         console.log("Output : ", $scope.output);
  });

});
```

In the controller, when I use `testService.getData().query().$promise.`, everything works fine. But when I change it to `testService.getData().save().$promise.`, it throws an error:

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration

I am returning a JSON type from play. I read that save() expects an object and query() an Array type? Why is it not working then? When I check in the browser, I am getting the JSON data in the response.But in controller I am unable to use it. Please see the pics below.

Error:

[image]

Response in browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you provided seems to be not the whole log for me. So I can only make an assumption here.

By default, save method of **$resource** service expects the response to be a JSON object, and your response is **an array** of JSON objects, so it throws an error.

If it's the case, you can quickly fix that by adding **isArray** this to your config: (the same fix can be applied to other **$resource** functions such as **get**, **remove**, **query**)

```
save: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Auth-Token': 'B1016693LCAP8154'
            },
            isArray: true
        }
```